# Триггер onEdit(e): всплывающее окно с предупреждением, при изменении любой ячейки в столбце

Tags: google-apps-script

Всем, здравствуйте.
Нужно, чтобы при изменении любой ячейки в столбце "Е" на "Включено", если в этой строке пустая ячейка "В" и "С" или "D"— всплывало окно с предупреждением с кнопкой "ОК".
То есть, статус "Включено" разрешен, если в строке заполнены: 1)"B,C"; 2)"B,D"; 3)"B,C,D".
Строк на листе со временем будет более тысячи.
Попытался написать скрипт, но ничего не выходит. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Лист1')
  var cellIvalue = sheet.getRange('E2:E').getValue();
  var cellBvalue = sheet.getRange('B2:B').getValue();
  var cellCvalue = sheet.getRange('C2:C').getValue();
  var cellDvalue = sheet.getRange('D2:D').getValue();
  
  if (cellIvalue == 'Включено'&& cellBvalue.CELL_EMPTY)
    
  {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var message = ui.alert(
      'Alert text"',  
  ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выкладываю, два варианта скрипта. Делают одно и тоже, но реализация разная.
Спасибо ребятам с англ. ветки форума, за [помощь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045288/trigger-onedit-e-popup-with-a-warning-when-any-cell-in-the-column-changes?noredirect=1#comment113262580_64045288). Код, который я пытался написать, это конечно вообще жесть.

1 вариант.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  if(as.getName() == 'Лист1' && col == 5 && row > 2 && e.range.getValue() == 'Enable'){
    
    if(as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,4).isBlank() ){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Start date'\n and\n 'Expiration date' or 'Amount'";
     }
    else if (as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && (!as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() || !as.getRange(row,4).isBlank()) ){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Start date'";
     }
    else if (!as.getRange(row,2).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,3).isBlank() && as.getRange(row,4).isBlank()){
     var message = "Enter data into the cell:\n 'Expiration date' or 'Amount'";
     }
    if(message){
        ui.alert(message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
        as.getRange(row,col).clearContent();
    }     
    }
  }
```

2 вариант

```
    'use strict';
/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} param1
 */
function onEdit({
  value: v,
  range: { rowStart: r, columnStart: c },
  range: rg,
}) {
  /*Exit code*/
  if (
    v !== 'Enable' ||
    r < 2 ||
    c !== 5 ||
    rg.getSheet().getName() !== 'Sheet1'
  )
    return;

  const [[startDate, expirationDt, amount]] = rg
      .offset(0, -3, 1, 3)
      .getValues(),
    showAlert = () => {
      const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert('Invalid Data', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    },
    isEmpty = e => e === '';

  //if startDate is empty or both expirationDt & amount is empty, showAlert and clear range
  if (isEmpty(startDate) || [expirationDt, amount].every(isEmpty)){
    showAlert(); 
    rg.clear();
  }
}
```